# material-ui components such as DropDownMenu stop working when using redux-devtools + hot reloading

Tags: redux, material-ui, redux-devtools

I have been using redux and redux dev-tools for about a week now and I'm loving it. I'm a big fan of Material Design and so I thought I should give material-ui a try.

It was all good until I used components other than buttons such as [DropDownMenu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu).

The dropdown menu seems to stop working after the initial load. Here's my component:

```
<DropDownMenu value={locale} onChange={languageChangeHandler}>
   <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="English"/>
   <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Arabic"/>
</DropDownMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround:

I had to `injectTapEventPlugin()` *everytime* the app is rendered (when the store state changes) otherwise it won't work after the initial load. This made the `DropDownMenu` work when using hot reloading.

There is an open issue to address the `injectTapEventPlugin()` situation => https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1011